# I want to learn Sanskrit. Can anybody guide me how to start?

Tags: sanskrit, book-recommendation

I want to learn Sanskrit. Can anybody guide me how to start???
Because I know Marathi, Hindi , English three languages I can not justified which medium will help me to learn Sanskrit in easy and perfect way.

Comment: I think whichever language is comfortable to you you can learn it in that. Because the idea is to understand Sanskrit easily.

Comment: @Surya Do u have any reference books for Sanskrit in hindi??

Comment: May http://sanskritdocuments.org/learning_tools/ help you.

Comment: @rohit devlekar: Also, join here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98070/sanskrit-language

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are tons of resources both online and offline.

## Offline Sources

1. [samskritabharati](http://samskritabharati.in/) is an organisation of volunteers who are committed to Sanskrit, and they conduct free Sanskrit classes. They have many years of experience at this, and teach spoken Sanskrit without going through an intimidating grammar-only approach. Look at [Samskrit in your locality](http://samskritabharati.in/local) and see if there are any upcoming classes in your area. If not (the website is not very properly updated), contact Samskrita Bharati and ask if they are conducting any. Even if they have nothing planned, if you have about 10-20 students, they are often willing to come and teach at your place (for free).
2. A set of recorded classes by Samskrita Bharati (commissioned and published by the Rashtriya Sanskrit Sansthan, and sold by the [RSkS](http://sanskrit.nic.in/) at Rs [1200 for 30 DVDs](http://www.sanskrit.nic.in/publication/av.pdf)). You may also be able to do a Google search for the title “Sanskrit Bhasha Shikshanam” and see some of the videos as a sample.
3. If you are interested in certificate courses and degree/pg courses, I encourage you to look at RSkS's distance education program offered as [MuktasvadhyayaPeetham](http://sanskrit.nic.in/msp.htm). They offer certificate courses of short duration or undergrad and graduate degrees in Sanskrit. Have a look [here](http://sanskrit.nic.in/msp/advertisments.htm)

## Online Sources

1. ["A Practical Sanskrit Introductory" by Charles Wikner](http://sanskritdocuments.org/learning_tutorial_wikner/wikner.pdf). This is a short introduction that is both excellent and strange, and for the same reasons. It goes into very great detail on the sounds of the language and the Devanagari script (even if you think you know this, you’ll probably find something new here), and in a parallel track discusses some points of grammar.
2. [Very nicely typeset grammar tutorial.](http://www.learnsanskrit.org/grammar)
3. [Other sources](http://sanskritdocuments.org/learning_tools/)
4. Course offered by IITM, [Acharya](http://www.acharya.gen.in:8080/sanskrit/lessons.php)
5. [OpenPathshaala](http://www.openpathshala.com/) is a video tutorial content website along the lines of Khan Academy. Have a look at their site.
6. A Youtube video lecture series by the name [Samskritham Amrutham](http://m.youtube.com/channel/UCecnNCCL87bKO3uDQ0bjRLA?desktop_uri=%2Fchannel%2FUCecnNCCL87bKO3uDQ0bjRLA).

Happy learning.

Comment: I am looking for the sources for learning Sanskrit grammar from Hindi language.

Comment: @Pandya The best way to learn Sanskrit from your mother tongue is via SamskritaBharati (refer the first bullet).

Comment: @VineetMenon http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29992648#29992648

Comment: Could you suggest some for Hindi speakers which doesn't include English?

Comment: It is a shame we can't favorite answers.