# Guidance to read and understand Hinduism

Tags: vedas, upanishads, sanskrit

I have keen interest in Hinduism and I want to read all the vedas and upnishads. So I have some questions to start :

1. Best resource to teach myself sanskrit so that I can understand vedas and upnishads.
2. Sequential list of all the vedas, upanishads and granthas I should read to understand the teachings. And where can I get them offline or online?

Thanks

Comment: Refer: [What are some online sources to get unabridged Hindu Scriptures or to learn Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15424/277)

Comment: and also [I want to learn Sanskrit. Can anybody guide me how to start?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9676/5212)