# Where can I learn Sanskrit?

Tags: sanskrit

I want to learn Sanskrit to understand the words of Vedas,Upanishads.
So,is there any reliable source on internet to learn Sanskrit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to learn Sanskrit. Can anybody guide me how to start?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9676/i-want-to-learn-sanskrit-can-anybody-guide-me-how-to-start)

Answer (score 1):

Madras sanskrit college is conducting basic sanskrit courses online . you may try if you are interested .
https://digital.madrassanskritcollege.edu.in/site/home